# php pagination with sql query.only want 10 results per page

Tags: php, sql

i want to show only 10 items per page, right now i get the entire 200 on the same page

```
<?php
if($dosare_work[0] != "")
{
?>
<ul>
<?php
for($j = 0;$j < count($dosare_work);$j++)
{
$details_work = explode(",",$dosare_work[$j]);

$sql = "SELECT titlu_dosar FROM detalii_dosar WHERE id_dosar = '".$details_work[1]."'";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die("Query failed with error: ".mysql_error());
$row_titlu = mysql_fetch_array($result);

print '<li style="-webkit-border-radius:0px 0 0 0px;box-shadow:0px 0px 5px #000; 
-moz-border-radius:0px 0 0 0px; background-color:#efefef;margin:0px 0px 5px 0px">
                    <div class="icon doc"></div><a href="/detalii/'.$details_work[1].'"><span style="font-weight:100">'.$row_titlu['titlu_dosar'].'</span><br/>'.$details_work[0].' </a></li>';


}
?>`
```

Comment: Use `LIMIT 10` in your query.

Comment: Hi user3775072, which database are you using?

Answer (score 0):

To only get 10 results you should put LIMIT 10 at the end of your query.

The full query would look like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT titlu_dosar FROM detalii_dosar WHERE id_dosar = '" .$details_work[1]. "' LIMIT 10"
```

Comment: that would only show me this page.at the end of the list i want to show page2,3,4,5,..etc... and on each page to show only 10 results

Comment: You could just save the number of results that you are at, for example  first do LIMIT 10 which gets the first 10 and then add LIMIT 10,10 which will start at 10 and then get 10 more rows.

Then just up the first value of the LIMIT by 10 every time.

LIMIT 20,10
LIMIT 30,10